# How to keep different session while using apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a site say www.example.com, I am using the apache mod_proxy to map another sub domain  sub.example.com to a url www.example.com/sub, but at the same time I need to keep different sessions on www.example.com and www.example.com/sub. Is it possible? 
I am using proxypass and proxypassreverese to achieve this.

```
    ProxyPass /sub http://sub.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse /sub http://sub.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `http://sub.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com/sub` then the cookies themselves should not conflict: Tomcat will issue a `JSESSIONID` cookie and the browser should tie that cookie to the host in use at the time (either www.example.com or sub.example.com).

Your configuration above seems to indicate that you are *always* using `www.example.com` and only re-naming the host behind the scenes.

You may have problems with this because Tomcat will assign a `JSESSIONID` cookie whose `Path` matches that of the context path as seen by Tomcat (i.e. `/` since you appear to be using the `ROOT` web application on Tomcat), and the client will always see the same hostname. The result will be two `JSESSIONID` cookies that will be passed on each request to `http://www.example.com/` if the user has visited both "applications" and received a cookie from each one. Tomcat will ignore any `JSESSIONID` cookie that does not match an existing session then there are more than one to choose from, but if more than one valid `JSESSIONID` cookie is available it can be sensitive to environmental factors such as header-ordering.

The best policy is to avoid having overlapping URL spaces for web applications that use authentication and/or cookies. Maybe deploy one web application on `/sub` and another on `/top`. Use the top-level (e.g. no path other than the resource name like `index.html`) for pages that don't use any cookies at all.

If you really want to meddle with things, you can look at using the `sessionCookiePath` of the `<Context>` element in your web application's `WEB-INF/context.xml` file. You could set it to `/sub` for the web application deployed on `/sub`. That might be able to help a little bit, but then you'd still have to have a separately-deployed (copy of your) web application in order to have a different cookie path for the `www.example.com`-deployed application. Basically, this all becomes a mess and it's more worth your time to untangle things to avoid the problem altogether.